# Find network key using ZBDSNIFF

Tags: security, xbee, zigbee

I create a ZigBee network using Xbee series 2 model xb24-z7wit-004.

I have sniff a lot of packets using AVRUSBSTICK with default firmware and save that in a .dump file.
After that i have converter this into dcf using zbconvert, but when i try to find network key using Zbdsniff, it process 2 files (.dump and .dcf) but it don't find any network key. I am sure that the communication is encrypt.

Thanks for support

Comment: Please include the encryption-related settings from the XBee modules (like `ATEE` and `ATEO`).  Also make sure `ATZS` is set to 2?

Comment: Are you sure that zbdsniff can extract the network key from an encrypted network?  My reading of that program implies that it's looking for keys sent "in the clear", which wouldn't be the case if you're using a link key when establishing the network.

Comment: Parameters: EE = 1, EO = 0 and ZS = 0.

Comment: tomlogic thanks for reply, i have found the network key when it is sent "in the clear". There is a way to discover this key if it is sent encrypt? thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to sniff and determine the network key without knowing the shared link key, which is used to encrypt that packet.